# Send data to Azure IoT Hub using Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to send data to Azure IoT Hub from Apache NiFi. Using Publish MQTT processor I am trying to publish data. Is this a right approach to send a data from NiFi to IoT Hub? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MQTT protocol directly (as a device) to send and receive data from Azure IoT Hub - like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device

As long as you can connect over TLS/SSL you should be fine.